# Android - ListView EditText Focus Issues

Tags: java, android, listview, focus, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` that I'm using as the footer `View` for my `ListView`. I'm attempting to access the focus / lose focus events, but for some reason, it's firing multiple times per focus. What is going on here?

```
// in onCreate

// ...

// the footer
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.comment_edittext, null );

EditText commentEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById( R.id.comment_edittext );
commentEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener( new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange( View v, boolean hasFocus )
    {
        U.log("View: " + v.getClass().getName().toString() );

        if( hasFocus )
        {
            U.log( "Clicked" );
        }
        else
        {
            U.log( "Un Clicked" );
        }
    }
} );

// add the footer
commentListView.addFooterView( v );

// ...
```

The output, of a single touch, which brings up the keyboard is:

```
04-11 10:22:17.449: E/004 - X(4576): View: android.widget.EditText
04-11 10:22:17.459: E/004 - X(4576): Clicked
04-11 10:22:17.569: E/004 - X(4576): View: android.widget.EditText
04-11 10:22:17.569: E/004 - X(4576): Un Clicked
04-11 10:22:17.569: E/004 - X(4576): View: android.widget.EditText
04-11 10:22:17.569: E/004 - X(4576): Clicked
04-11 10:22:17.689: E/004 - X(4576): View: android.widget.EditText
04-11 10:22:17.689: E/004 - X(4576): Un Clicked
04-11 10:22:17.709: E/004 - X(4576): View: android.widget.EditText
04-11 10:22:17.709: E/004 - X(4576): Clicked
```

I can kind of understand it calling multiple events with `hasFocus` set to `true`, but why then are there also `false`s, triggering the `Un Clicked` log?

**EDIT:** Furthermore, whenever I scroll the `ListView` up and down, moving the `EditText` in and out of view, it's calling these events as well. Am I using the wrong listener type perhaps?

Comment: my guess is your onCreate method is called several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience, EditTexts inside ListViews are a bane. Because of the way views are recycled and rendered, the focus behaves strangely. I recommend approaching the problem some other way. Actually, if it's a comment text box, wouldn't it be better if it was always visible?

Sample layout:

```
  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <ListView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/> 
    <EditText 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My initial attempt was to just place it after the ListView in my layout's XML file. It wouldn't render however, so I figured it had something to do with the ListView's downward expansion. If there is a way to do that, I'd be open to it.

Comment: Added the layout I use for exactly the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use a GridView instead and give a numColumns of 1. If you don't like how that reads in your java classes, store them as an AbsListView (and just keep them as a GridView in your xml).

ListView is buggy with EditTexts, GridViews lack those problems.

Comment: Tried this without seeing any difference

Answer (score 0):

Using Grideview with a numColumns of 1 is the perfect way to solove the problem. I have try it and solve my problem .